# "Algorithm 'RS256' could not be found. Do you have cryptography installed?" Issue with JWT for AWS Lambda (Python)

Tags: aws-lambda, jwt, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I created a Rest API for Campaign Management 360 with a service account. The lambda needs to pull 360 campaign data , and then load them into S3 buckets. *I need to generate a access token and would prefer not to do that manually* since daily pulls will be done. So what I did is:

1. I get the credentials from the *services-account.json* file.
2. I then extract the private key from the file which is passed as an argument along with the private key ID, client_email, and Scopes of the dfareporting type.
3. I then call a function to create the Signed JWT (thisis where the problem is)
4. Finally, I call a function to exchange the JWT for the access token.

> My issue is that when the code enters the Signed JWT function, it crashes giving me this error:
> [image]
> **Here's my lambda_handler which triggers the call**:
> [image]

> **And here's the module containing the functions to create and exchange the JWT for an access token.**
> [image]

> I import the JWT library into my code which has to the latest version so I am not sure why it's not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days we were able to contact our company's client and as it turned out , we didn't have to concern ourselves with manually creating modules dealing with JWT signing.  The client's business analyst indicated that the client had originally given us a test profile Id and so he was able to give use the production Profile ID.

> As soon as we used that profile ID , the Service Account triggered and
> refreshed it's new access token. So we removed the JWT signing module and used something similar to this instead:

```
service_account_key = getenv(
        'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS',
        f'{expanduser(".")}servicegoogle.json'
    )   

    # Creates a credentials object from the service account file
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        service_account_key, # key path
        # scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'] # scopes
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ddmconversions", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking"] # scopes
    )

    # Prepare an authentication request
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

    # Request refresh tokens
    credentials.refresh(auth_req)

    # now we can print the access token
    print('<< CREDENTIALS >> ',credentials.token)
    return credentials.token
```

> And in the calling Lambda we used these instructions to update the
> credentials token with the new access token created in the function
> call above:

```
#print('<< Crednetials >>', str(credentials))
    # Create an access token using the refresh token
    refreshed_token = create_access_token()
    #Update the credentials with the refreshed token
    credentials.token = refreshed_token
    #print('<< CREDENTIALS TOKEN >> ',credentials.token)
    # Build the Campaign Manager 360 API client using the updated credentials
    gcm360_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('dfareporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```